# No encuentra la ruta del archivo CSS y JS ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) .NET

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación de donde se agendan citas. en base cuando abren la aplicación inmediatamente les muestra el calendario con las citas agendadas y al dar click en un recuadro se puede agendar una cita.

En local si me muestra el calendario, a la hora de que subo el proyecto al servidor IIS me manda el error 404 la carpet con los archivos css y js si estan cargados en la ruta pero a la hora de abrirlo en el servidor me manda el error.

Me podrían ayudar en solucionarlo?

```bash
GET http://srv-webtest/Andres/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el código lo tengo de la siguiente manera:

```html
<link href="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/daygrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/timegrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

```html
<script src="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="../vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asp.Net utiliza una carpeta para los ficheros estáticos tales como css y js en el caso de Asp.Net MVC5 se llama Content y en Asp.Net Core wwwroot te recomiendo utilizar `~` sobre `..` al referenciar los archivos estáticos, esto te garantiza que tanto en producción como en desarrollo tu app valla siempre a la carpeta correcta a la hora de llamar los archivos.

por tanto asumiendo que tienes tus archivos js en la carpeta vendors que a su vez se encuentra dentro de wwwroots en caso de Asp.Net core o Content en caso de MVC5 deberías llamarlo de esta manera:

```
 <script src="~/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/interaction/main.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/daygrid/main.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/timegrid/main.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

En relación a tu consulta, en mi caso, no utilizo ni puntos ni virgulilla, simplemente lo escribo así:

```html
<link href="vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/Core/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/daygrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="vendors/FULLCALENDAR-4-1-0-DESCARGA/timegrid/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Debido a que las archivos de páginas principales siempre las mantengo en raíz, y solo amerita realizar llamados a las subcarpetas.

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que leas [answer].

Comment: No olvides _siempre_ darle formato de código al código. Si revisás la versión anterior de tu respuesta, notarás que el código no se visualizaba. Esto está relacionado al formato de Markdown.